# Android Program Name - What determines this name in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, project, package

Very simple question here:

I have an android project in Eclipse. Not understanding how packages work, I see a hundred different names for my project floating around.

Which is the specific attribute of the project that determines the name of the app as the user sees it on their phone?

As a follow up, how do I modify this.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your AndroidManifest.xml

Look for the line

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" ... >
```

The attribute of the application android:label defines what the name of the app is on the device and the android:icon attribute defines what is used for the icon in the launcher. In this case, it is saying the android:label is referencing a value app_name of the type String. This will be located in

```
/res/values/strings.xml
```

something like

```
<string name="app_name">Hello World App</string>
```